# CSS Transition with greensock

Tags: css, gsap

Is there any way to change the border color with greensock from top to down.
It's the simple line div and want to change its color from top to down, e.g.:

```css
.line {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #c3ced8;
  width: 0;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  z-index: 1;
  top: -19px;
  margin: 0;
  left: 5.3px;
  margin-bottom: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```

Want to change its border color from top to down with greensock lib.

Comment: What do you mean by top to down ?

Comment: @klugjo change the border color from top to down. It's the vertical line and want to change its color without using before or after tag. (means adding no more div.)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the `border-image: linear-gradient()`, e.g.:

```css
.line {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 0;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  z-index: 1;
  top: -19px;
  margin: 0;
  left: 5.3px;
  margin-bottom: -30px;
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f00, #00f) 1;
  -o-border-image: -o-linear-gradient(#f00, #00f) 1;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f00, #00f) 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```